# XSD - List with all fixed values

Tags: xml, xsd, xmlschema

What would be the correct XML Schema declaration for:

```
...<answersList>
    <question quest="Name?" cod="n_name">Variable Content</question>
    <question quest="Weight?" cod="n_weight">Variable Content</question>
</answersList>...
```

Every value for both attributes should be in the XSD enumeration.

So far I tried: (It doesen't work)

```
        <xs:element name="question">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="quest">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="Name?"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="Weight?"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="cod">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="n_name"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="n_weight"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:attribute>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

Using this web to test:
https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

Comment: Either define a fixed value, or define an enumeration facet with only one value in the list.

Comment: @MichaelKay I dont see how to do fixed values for a list. Im trying to do it with enumeration but it keeps failing for me :/

Comment: And I'm afraid I just don't understand your question. I don't see any lists in your data, and and I can't see why you want quest to be a fixed value when your instance has two quest attributes with different values. I suspect you are using both the terms "list" and "fixed value" in a sense quite different from their actual meaning in the XSD specification, which doesn't aid communication.

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes you are completly right. I wasn't even understanding what I wanted. 
Im trying to get an enumeration for 2 attributes for the tag question.

Comment: At the example the idea is that the tag "quest" only should validate if it contains "Name?" or Weight?. And the tag "cod" should only validate if it contains: "n_name" or "n_weight"

Comment: Right, I was coming to that conclusion. So, nothing to do with lists or fixed values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML Schema, the name of a tag identifies its type and the type describes the allowed content. When a tag repeats, each occurrence has the *same* type.

So you cannot apply one set of rules to the attributes in `//answersList/question[1]` and a different set of rules to the attributes in `//answersList/question[2]`.

Comment: The idea I have is to apply the same rules for all questions, but different rules in attribute[1.1] and attribute[1.2]. Do you have any idea on how to make the concept xsd i did to work and validate? Im like 12h in and still havent been able to make it "compile"

Thanks for answering!

Comment: It's not clear (to me, anyway) what you are trying to do. Your XSD snippet is clearly not valid because you do not have any simpleType definition for the attributes. Does that help at all?

Comment: Yes my XSD is not valid. Im trying to get both attributes to have an enumeration for what they can store and what they cant. At the example the idea is that the tag quest only should validate if it contains "Name?" or Weight?.
And the tag cod should only validate if it contains: "n_name" or "n_weight"

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you are actually looking for is cross-node constraints: "if X is A then Y must be B". That can be achieved using assertions in XSD 1.1; it can't be achieved in XSD 1.0.

You can constrain each of the attributes to a fixed set of values using an enumeration type (a simple type defined by restricting `xs:string` with an enumeration facet), and you can define cross-attribute constraints using assertions, provided that you use an XSD 1.1 processor.